# Determine Polygon with specified property

Tags: c++, algorithm, polygon

I am creating a graphics project in which I have to find at some point of time that if there exists a point `x` inside the polygon such that if I join this point to all vertices of this polygon then all the line segments joining vertices and this point `x` lies completely inside the Polygon.

I wonder if there is some famous algorithm to do so or could any one of you describe an algorithm to do so.

I am looking for a linear time algorithm.

Comment: I'm assuming your polygon is concave?  If it is convex, then you are guaranteed that all lines from a vertex to an interior point are completely within the polygon.

Comment: The technical term is star-shaped: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon

Comment: To follow up on the comment by @Henrik - the linked article describes how to solve your problem by finding the _kernel_ of the polygon. There's a link to a paper that describes an O(n) (linear time) algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I didn't know the technical term. Now I will look into that and will let you know.

Comment: It might not be what you're looking for, but once you find the kernel of the polygon, an easy way to test if your point is within is is to: generate a test point you think is within the kernel, then generate a point you know is *outside* the kernel.  Connect the two points and count how many edges of the kernel it crosses over.  If it's an odd number, the point lies within the kernel, if it's even, the point is outside the kernel.
Also, does anybody know if the kernel generated from a star-shaped polygon is guaranteed to be convex or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to compute the kernel of a star-shaped polygon. This problem was solved in 1979 by Lee and Preparata in a paper entitled [An Optimal Algorithm for Finding the Kernel of a Polygon](http://asignatura.us.es/fgcitig/Articulos/03-An%20optimal%20algorithm%20for%20finding%20the%20kernel%20of%20a%20polygon.pdf). From their abstract:

> The kernel `K(P)` of a simple polygon `P` with `n` vertices is the locus of
>   the points internal to `P` from which all vertices of `P` are visible
>   Equivalently, `K(P)` is the intersection of appropriate half-planes
>   determined by the polygon's edges. Although it is known that to find
>   the intersection of `n` generic half-planes requires time `O(n log n)`, we
>   show that one can exploit the ordering of the half-planes
>   corresponding to the sequence of the polygon's edges to obtain a
>   kernel finding algorithm which runs in time `O(n)` and is therefore
>   optimal.